# Navigation sub menu auto center

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with my navigation sub menu.
The theme I'm using is Flexfrom which you can find here: http://flexform.swiftideas.net/

As you can see the sub menu at my page doesn't automatically centers with the text, while it does in the theme demo.
What did I do wrong?
Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Could you add a jsFiddle with the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it on line 93, although it requires a set width.

```
nav .menu ul {
border: 0;
display: none;
height: auto;
width: 100px;
left: 50%;
margin: 0;
margin-left: -50px;
min-width: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
z-index: 9995;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked.
I've solved the set width problem with: max-width.
That seems to work fine too.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept the answer when you are able :)

Comment: Have to wait for 1 more minute :) Will do afterwards Thanks